# Regex - match a string without having spaces

Tags: javascript, regex, spaces

Building an regular expression that will reject an input string which contain spaces.

I have a following expression, but its not working as well;

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#*()+{}[\\];:,|\/\\\\_\S-]+$
```

**Valid case**

```
String123/test //string without space
```

**Invalid case**

```
String123/ test // contains space in between string 

String 123/test // contains space in between string 

 String123/test  // contains leading\trailing space
```

i.e; I have to white list strings which does not contain any spaces.

Comment: Is it only the space you want to reject or there is another characters?

Comment: console.log(!(/\s/.test('this is'))); This would be the case

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/9gvVmm/1

Answer (score 17):

You may use `\S`

`\S` matches any non white space character

**Regex**

```
/^\S+$/
```

**Example**

```js
function CheckValid(str){
   re = /^\S+$/
   return re.test(str)
 }


console.log(CheckValid("sasa sasa"))
console.log(CheckValid("sasa/sasa"))                      
console.log(CheckValid("sas&2a/sasa"))
```

Comment: @Justin please  accept the answer if it solved the problem

Comment: Works fine !! Thanks Sarath.

Comment: In Sublime Text it'll be (^\S+$)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you'll be using .test method on regex, `/\s/g` this one should do the job, it will return true if there's any space in the string.
ex: `/\s/g.test("String123/test")` this will return false which means that the string is valid
`/\s/g.test("String123 /test)` this will return true which means that the string is not valid